# cpu: unreasonable faster when executing a heavy process

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-speed

I am developing a DAQ software on Scientific Linux 7.
A 8 CPU cores, core i7.
Recently, I figure out one thing: when someone execute ROOT (CERN) on the same computer, my DAQ would be faster.
Say, x1.5 times faster. 
(When ROOT application is executed, CPU is (almost) always 100%.)

This is unreasonable for me.
I think, if the PC is busy, the DAQ should be slower.
But reality is faster? why?

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Mike: sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pics%20or%20it%20didn%27t%20happen

Comment: @Mike: but it really happens. that's why I posted the question

Comment: Lots of times we think that one thing is happening, while in fact something else is happening.  We cannot really answer this question unless we see what is happening, and also see how you determined that what is happening is in fact what you say is happening.  It would be very difficult for you to provide us with all that information.  The comment about "pictures" were just a joke, hinting at the hopelessness of the situation.

Comment: hum .... i am still thinking ...

Comment: @MikeNakis
Hi, I have two questions: